# Is there a way to get HTML text in VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba

The following is a sample of the HTML Document I am working with

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
    Some text here
    <div class="some class here">Some title here</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

My code is the following:

```
With HTMLDocument.getElementsByTagName("table")(iTable)
    For Each Tr In .Rows
        For Each Td In Tr.Cells
            Debug.Print Td.innerText
            Sheets(UserDataSheetName).Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = Td.innerText
            iCol = iCol + 1
        Next Td
        iCol = Col_Num_To_Start
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Next Tr
End With
```

Currently, what happens is that Td.innerText in my code not only gets the text "Some text here", but it also saves "Some title here" into my excel spreadsheet. Is there a way I can do it such that I only save "Some text here" into the spreadsheet?

Comment: Are all of the `Td.innerText` prints formatted the same?  If so, `Split` could be an option.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with methods like `getElementsByTagName()`, you work with the DOM (Document Object Model). The DOM builds a tree of nodes from all elements of a page. There are 12 different node types. One of them is `text`. A `text`node is text which stands alone without a html tag. So you can't get it's value with `innertext`. You have to use `textContent`. To pick the right node, you can pick a html node before and than use commands like `FirstChild` and `NextSibling` to reach the wanted text node.

Look here for more infos about DOM nodes:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp

For your example it works in this way:

```
Sub GetTextNode()

  Dim html As String
  Dim doc As Object
  
  html = "<table><tbody><tr><td>Some text here<div class='some class here'>Some title here</div></td></tr></tbody></table>"
  Set doc = CreateObject("htmlFile")
  doc.body.innerhtml = html
  
  MsgBox doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).FirstChild.textContent

End Sub
```

Comment: Also,`doc.querySelector("tbody > tr > td").FirstChild.NodeValue` with MSHTML.HTMLDocument  or with yours also `.nodeValue`.

Answer (score 0):

To make the macro work with an external source such as a webpage, we’ll need Microsoft’s Internet Explore (to open the page and will remain hidden). In-addition, to read and extract contents of HTML elements, we’ll have to create few objects using a library.

Therefore, first add the Microsoft HTML Object Library reference to the application. From the top menu of your VBA editor, click Tools -> References…. In the References window, find and select Microsoft HTML Object Library and click OK.